# Create generic List<T> in a Base class and use it in derived classes with different T

Tags: c#, generics

I have Base class and Manager class derived from it :

```
public class CBase<TC> where TC : class, new()
    {
        protected CBase() {}
        protected static ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<TC>> _instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<TC>>();

        public static TC GetInstance(object key)
        {
            return _instances.GetOrAdd(key, k => new Lazy<TC>(() => new TC())).Value;
        }
    }

public class CSeriesManager : CBase<CSeriesManager>
    {
        private List<CSeries.SSeries> _items = null;
        public List<CSeries.SSeries> Series 
        {
            get 
            {
                if (_items == null) _items = new List<CSeries.SSeries>();
                return _items;
            }
        }
    }
```

I will have several manager classes and each of them will have field similar to List with a check for NULL in getter. Is it possible to make this field generic and move it to Base class without excess boxing / casting?

This is what I have so far :

```
public class CBase<TC> where TC : class, new()
    {
        protected CBase() {}
        protected List<object> _items = new List<object>();
        protected static ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<TC>> _instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<TC>>();

        public static TC GetInstance(object key)
        {
            return _instances.GetOrAdd(key, k => new Lazy<TC>(() => new TC())).Value;
        }

        public List<TL> GetItems<TL>()
        {
            return _items.ConvertAll(x => (TL)x);
        }
    }
```

Does anybody have suggestions of how to improve / speed up it?

Comment: why don't you just include the type-parameter `TL` into the generic definition of `CBase<TC,TL>`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense: `CSeriesManager : CBase<CSeriesManager>`.

Comment: Where did the `TL` in `List<TL>` come from? How is it defined?

Comment: @PatrickHofman here it's a parameter of the method (methods can be generic)

Comment: @Carsten König : because I may have multiple fields and it will look a bit wierd to include all field types into class declaration, e.g. CBase<TC,TL,TB,TN, ...> although I would like to know - is it possible to include multiple types into class declaration dynamically, without mentioning of them in a base class, e.g. CBase<TC, params Type[]> but somewhere in code I will call it like CBase<TC,TL>?

Comment: @Art it looks weird because your class does way to much ;) (mind the **S** in **S**olid ;) )

Comment: @Art: if you want those fields to have generic behavior, you have to.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman : CSeriesManager : CBase<CSeriesManager> - actually it makes sense when you want thread safe class but the method that creates new instances moved to the base class, in this case you simply need to inform base class about the type of instance that needs to be created

Comment: @Art: these classes (`CBase` and `CSeriesManager`) have different responsibilities. While `CBase` is some sort of caching/instance management provider, `CSeriesManager` is something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
public class CBase<TC, LT> where TC : class, new()
{
    protected CBase() {}
    protected static ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<TC>> _instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<TC>>();

    public static TC GetInstance(object key)
    {
        return _instances.GetOrAdd(key, k => new Lazy<TC>(() => new TC())).Value;
    }

    private List<LT> _items = null;
    public List<LT> Series 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_items == null) _items = new List<LT>();
            return _items;
        }
    }
}

public class CSeriesManager : CBase<CSeriesManager, SSeries>
{
}
```

Comment: yes, something like this but would be good not to be limited to only 2 types in CBase<Type1, Type2>, is it possble to pass multiple types into base class this way?

Comment: exactly what i was going to write :)

Comment: @Art - You can do as many as you want. I'm sure that there's a limit, but I've never hit it. I do suggest though, that if you have many generic parameters then your design is faulty. I can't think of too many times where I would have used more than 4.

Comment: @Enigmativity : ok, agree, design was not good, so I changed it a little